# Open a ViewController if a cell of a TableViewController is clicked

Tags: swift

i'm trying to create a view controller programmatically that will be opened if a cell on a table is clicked. i'm using a table view and i'm filling it with a xib.So, i'm stuck at the point of referencing the new view controller from the first one on click on a cell created in the table view via xib.

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DViewController") as? DViewController
    self.navigationController?.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil) //present della view successiva
    vc?.name = data[indexPath.row].nome
    
}
```

this code allows me to click on the row but when clicked it shows an error "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" generated apparently from the self.navigationController?.present(vc!...the vc value result to be nil and i can't figure out why.
THis is the ViewController that i want to open on click and the only thing that it has to do is open and change the tile to the name ow the cell that i've clicked onto in the other ViewController

```
class DViewController: UITableViewController {

var name = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "\(name)"
}
```

}

Can someone help?i'm new to swift...ty

Comment: `vc?.name = data[indexPath.row].nome` should be assigned before the controller is presented. Alternative check if `vc` is nil in the debugger.

Comment: the vc from the debugger is nil but i can't figure out why

Comment: Did you check your identifier in the storyboard to be exactly `DViewController`? Did you set the viewcontroller class to `DViewController`?

Comment: i thought it so but the fact is that i have nothing on the storyboard, the DViewController is created programmatically...by code not in the storyboard

Comment: then why this `storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DViewController") as? DViewController` ?

Comment: i thought that it could be the issue but i'm kinda new to swift...how should I rewrite that?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/showing_and_hiding_view_controllers I really think you should start with the basics.

Comment: i know but i'm stuck on this and i need to solve it or i wont't sleep anymore...i know that the solution is easy

Comment: The solution is not easy. You seem not to know of the basic navigation techniques of UIKit. Learn them by doing tutorials and reading documentations. There is no easy fix here.

Comment: the fact is that i've already done all the possible tutorials and read the basic documentation yet but i don't know how to use the instantiateViewController without a storyboard

Comment: Always try to give a meaningful name to the class like ```DetailViewController```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you mentioned. You can initialize your viewController without stroyboard, and there is no crash anymore.

```
let vc = DViewController()
```

If you present your view controller like what you did, it won’t display the title you wish.
To display the title, there are 2 ways you can do:

Display your new view controller with Pushing style:

```
let vc = DViewController() 
navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Keep using presenting style, but you need to wrap your view controller in other navigation controller:

```
let vc = DViewController()
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
navigationController?.present(nav, animated: true)
```

Comment: only thing i've added vc.title = data[indexPath.row].name to let vc = DViewController()
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
navigationController?.present(nav, animated: true) but i't doesn't show the name of the content of the cell i've clicked on

Comment: Have you tried to assign string for testing to vc.title? like: vc.title = "Hello". Does it display the title or not?